# how to make value different from items in DropdownButtonFormField flutter so user chose item from [max,jac] but the value would be [a,b]

Tags: flutter

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
                        isDense: true,
                        hint: Text('select mode'),
                        items: _modes.map((String mode) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: mode,
                            child: Text(mode),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          if (_connected) {
                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                              BluetoothHelper.show(
                                  _scaffoldKey, "please select mode");
                              return;
                            }
                            print(value);
                            print(textFieldController.text);
                            _sendTextMessageToBluetooth(value);
                            textFieldController.clear();
                          } else {
                            BluetoothHelper.show(
                                _scaffoldKey, "please connect to a device");
                          }
                        },
                      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
String dropvalue;
DropdownButton(
                      hint:Text("Text"),
                      isExpanded: true,
                      underline: SizedBox(),
                      value: _transaction.type,
                      items: ["max","jac"].map((valueitem){
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: valueitem,
                            child: Text('$valueitem'));
                      }).toList(), onChanged: (value){
                    setState(() {
                      if (value!="max"){
                        dropvalue= "a";
                      }else{
                        dropvalue="b";
                      }
                      _transaction.type = value;
                    });
                  }),
```